# Project a _id ref field as document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Consider the current collection:

```
# the manager
db.employees.insert({_id: ObjectId(
"4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"),
name: 'Leto'})


# the yours employees
db.employees.insert({_id: ObjectId(
"4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d731"),
name: 'Duncan',
manager: ObjectId(
"4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730")});

db.employees.insert({_id: ObjectId(
"4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d732"),
name: 'Moneo',
manager: ObjectId(
"4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730")});
```

With this model, Is possible recover the `employees` with the `manager` field with the literal `Leto` document? Something like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"), "name" : "Leto" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d731"), "name" : "Duncan", "manager" : { "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"), "name" : "Leto" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d732"), "name" : "Moneo", "manager" : { "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"), "name" : "Leto" } }
```

Rather than

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"), "name" : "Leto" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d731"), "name" : "Duncan", "manager" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d732"), "name" : "Moneo", "manager" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730") }
```

If not, how i can do it? Because i am worried in literally put the manager inside the `manager` field because this will be complex to update in the future

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** method of the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find)** cursor to iterate over documents that have the manager key (through the **[`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)** operator and the **[`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)** operator to check if it's an **`ObjectId`**) and within each loop you query the collection for the manager document with **[`findOne()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)** and assign it as a subdocument for the `manager` property:

```
db.employees.find({"manager": {"$exists": true, "$type": 7}}).forEach(function (e){
    var manager = db.employees.findOne({"_id": e.manager});
    e.manager = manager;
    db.employees.save(e);
});

db.employees.find();
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"),
    "name" : "Leto"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d731"),
    "name" : "Duncan",
    "manager" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"),
        "name" : "Leto"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d732"),
    "name" : "Moneo",
    "manager" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"),
        "name" : "Leto"
    }
}
```